# Difference between glTexImage1D and glTexImage2D

Tags: opengl, textures

What is the difference between `glTexImage2D()` and `glTexImage1D()`? Actually, I can't imagine 1D texturing. How can something have a 1D texture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A texture is not a picture you draw onto triangles. A texture is a look-up table of values, which your shaders can access and get data from. You *can use* textures as "pictures you draw onto triangles", but you should not limit your thinking to just that.

A 1D texture is a texture with only one dimension: width. It's a line. It is a function of one dimension: `f(x)`. You provide one texture coordinate, and you get a value.

A 2D texture is a texture with two dimensions: width and height. It is a rectangle. It is a function of two dimensions: `f(x, y)`. You provide two texture coordinates, and you get a value.

A 1D texture can be used for a discrete approximation of any one-dimensional function. You could precompute some [Fresnel specular factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) and access a 1D texture to get them, rather than computing them in the shader. A 1D texture could represent the Gaussian specular term, as I do in [the first chapter on texturing in my book](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Texturing/Tutorial%2014.html).

A 1D texture can be any one-dimensional function.

Comment: Thank you Nicol! Your book was very helpful.

Comment: Wasn't `glTexImage1D` available in pre-shader OpenGL?

Comment: @Ruslan: Yes, but so were `glTexImage2D` and `glTexImage3D`.

Comment: Then it must have had some other use than a lookup table for a shader. What was it? I guess some fixed-function pipeline modes could use 1D textures specially, right?

Comment: @Ruslan: "*Then it must have had some other use than a lookup table for a shader.*" What are you talking about? *All textures* are lookup tables. There's nothing about fixed-function GL that requires textures to be pictures. The fixed-function pipeline may have been limited, but it was hardly as limited as just mapping fixed texture coordinates across a polygon. You may not have been able to do *arbitrary* texture coordinate computations, but you could do some computations.

Answer (score 2):

A 2D texture has both height and width whereas a 1D texture has a height of just 1 pixel.  This basically means that the texture is a line of pixels.  They are frequently used when we want to map some numeric value to a colour or map colour to a different colour (as in cell-shading techniques).